# Angular 4 production builld css blocked by CSP in Chrome Firefox but not IE

Tags: angular, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox, content-security-policy

I have my Angular production build deployed in static resources of my Java Springboot.
I tested it to run in 3 different browsers (Chrome, Firefox, IE) and received a blocked css in both Chrome and Firefox.

Some of the messages I retrieved in Chrome is:

```
Refuse to apply inline style.......
```

While in Firefox:

```
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at self (“style-src......
```

But everything loads fine in IE

How to resolve the issue in both Chrome and Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer essentially does not have Content Security Policy: it only supports the [Sandbox directive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP#compatNote_3). With Edge already out, it's safe to say Internet Explorer will never receive proper CSP support. So it 'works' because it's not being enforced whatsoever. IE shouldn't be part of your CSP testing.

The Chrome warning is quite informative, read it in full; it will tell you exactly what you need to do and even give a SHA hash you can use, something like:

```
style-src 'sha256-076c8f1ca6979ef156b510a121b69b6265011597557ca2971db5ad5a2743545f'
```

If your app has large amounts of inline code and you can't remove them `'unsafe-inline'` is a possibility but as the name implies it's not safe and not preferred.